# How to stop my excel sheets from changing places whenever vba is used?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA codage in my excel file that refresh with new information a page called ''assgination'' whenever I click the control button.

My sheet ''assignation'' should always stay in 4th position, but whenever it's refreshed, it goes to the last position.

how to stop making it move?

Comment: Without seeing the code we cannot help.  Please [edit] the post to include the code.

Comment: @Chadon Iegran, please can I have some feedbacks on my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57185759/11167163)

Answer (score 0):

Do **Alt + F11** go to **ThisWorkbook** from the left **Project Explorer** pane, double click it to open the Module then **paste** this. This code will lock your sheet **assignation** where you placed it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Application.ActiveSheet.Index <> Application.Sheets("assignation").Index Then
    Application.Sheets("assignation").Move Before:=Application.Sheets(Application.ActiveSheet.Index)
    Application.Sheets("assignation").Activate
    Sh.Activate
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

save and close this code, now, when you click any of your worksheet tab, this specific worksheet will be always at the front of your clicked sheet tab

Comment: It's not working. When I click on my process button, the ''assignation'' page always go to last sheet

Comment: @chadonlegran Did you paste it into **ThisWorkbook** ? not in a MODULE

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said !

Comment: @chadonlegran now close your workbook and re open it ;)

Comment: @chadonlegran this should replace the sheet in the right place

Comment: @chadonlegran if it does the job tell me we will just need to add something

Comment: @chadonlegran If your issue is fixed, may I ask you to accept this answer ?